# .htaccess rewrite condition won't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to have one page be forced to be http. So if https://www.test.com/dashboard is visited, it should be redirected to http://www.test.com/dashboard.

The .htaccess file is currently

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^dashboard$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.test.com/dashboard/$1 [R,L]
```

I also tried just triggering on the dashboard page no matter with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^dashboard$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.obviouslywrongsite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

But even that isn't triggered. Rewrites are working on the site.

Edit - Additionally, after cloning the Linode, using the latter .htaccess, the redirect works, but on the existing server, it doesn't work. I've emptied cache, used incognito mode, they simply behave differently. Apache config settings are exact mirrors. I have no idea where to proceed from here.

Comment: How about using `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on` instead of `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80`?

Comment: I actually just tried that and it still won't trigger.

Comment: Any other rewirte is working in the .htaccess? If no, you can check if the rewrite module is enabled.

Comment: Yep other rewrites do work, but even if I erase them all and only leave this one, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, only one liner RewriteRule work. Nothing with RewriteCond works.